# Does Microsoft support SignalR in Xamarin on Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, signalr

If I use the SignalR client within a Xamarin client, (specifically on Android) will I be able to log a request with Microsoft support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Microsoft does not support SignalR running under Xamarin on Android.